# Saving phpMyAdmin settings does not work

Tags: phpmyadmin

After installing phpMyAdmin on my Debian server, everything works fine except that saving settings opens the JSON answer as document and no settings are saved. Any ideas?

Comment: What settings are you trying to adjust? I was adjusting my PHP settings but this was dependant on the version of PHP I was using. So if I was using 5.6, then changing 5.5 wouldn't have an affect.

Comment: Any setting within Settings, such as Features->Version check, or Features->Hide databases

Answer (score 0):

that means the default settings are being used.  The configuration file is only for custom configurations.  As you have not created any custom configurations, the file will be empty.